# AJAX Request from 3 URLS to Populate Same Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint, datatables

Is it possible to have 3 different AJAX requests, and have them all populate to the same DataTable(table)? I have tried and tried to create a AJAX with multiple URLS and it didn't work, but when I used just one URL, it works fine. The issue is I need to pull from three different subsites.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable').DataTable({
    'ajax': {
      'url': "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('XDeliverables')/items?$select=Program, Deliverable, To, Date, Approved, Notes",
      'headers': { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata' },
      'dataSrc': function(data) {
        return data.value.map(function(item) {
          return [
            item.Program,
            item.Deliverable,
            item.To,
            item.Date,
            item.Approved,
            item.Notes
          ];
        });
      }
    },
    columnDefs: [{
     
    }]
  });
});
```

Is it possible to do something along the lines of: (or atleast something similar)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable').DataTable({
    'ajax': {
      'url': "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('XDeliverables')/items?$select=Program, Deliverable, To, Date, Approved, Notes",
      'headers': { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata' },
      'dataSrc': function(data) {
        return data.value.map(function(item) {
          return [
            item.Program,
            item.Deliverable,
            item.To,
            item.Date,
            item.Approved,
            item.Notes
          ];
        });
      }
    },
    'ajax': {
      'url': "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('YDeliverables')/items?$select=Program, Deliverable, To, Date, Approved, Notes",
      'headers': { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata' },
      'dataSrc': function(data) {
        return data.value.map(function(item) {
          return [
            item.Program,
            item.Deliverable,
            item.To,
            item.Date,
            item.Approved,
            item.Notes
          ];
        });
      }
    },
    'ajax': {
      'url': "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ZDeliverables')/items?$select=Program, Deliverable, To, Date, Approved, Notes",
      'headers': { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata' },
      'dataSrc': function(data) {
        return data.value.map(function(item) {
          return [
            item.Program,
            item.Deliverable,
            item.To,
            item.Date,
            item.Approved,
            item.Notes
          ];
        });
      }
    },
    columnDefs: [{
     
    }]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the ajax calls separately and concatenate the results together and then create the datatable

First make a function with all your ajax calls

```
async function getTableData() {
let baseURL = "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${type}')/items?$select=Program, Deliverable, To, Date, Approved, Notes"

let tempURL = baseURL.replace("${type}", "XDeliverables");
let response1 = await $.ajax({
  url: tempURL,
  headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata' }
});

tempURL = baseURL.replace("${type}", "YDeliverables");
let response2 = $.ajax({
  url: tempURL,
  headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata' }
});

tempURL = baseURL.replace("${type}", "ZDeliverables");
let response3 = $.ajax({
  url: tempURL,
  headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata' }
});

let dataSet = [...response1, ...response2, ...response3];

// call function that creates the datatable
initializeTable(dataSet);

};
```

Then just initialize the table with the data

```
function initializeTable(dataSet) {

    $('#myTable').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Position" },
            { title: "Office" },
            { title: "Extn." },
            { title: "Start date" },
            { title: "Salary" }
        ]
    });
};
```

Some docs.

[async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await%5D)

[Js source DataTable](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)

Comment: What is the "${type}" part of baseURL.replace("${type}", "XDeliverables");

Comment: I noticed that the url string only changed in that segment, that's why I set the baseURL variable at the beginning of the function (thats just me, I like to structure code this way). The function `replace()`does not modify the original string. But if you have trouble with that, just put the full path in the ajax call. [replace function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-string-replace/)